# ElasticSearch SearchTemplate request Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm stuck with a `SearchTemplate` request, until now I've been able to write queries through the `QueryBuilder` and execute them calling the "search" method of the `RestHighLevelClient` java client, but when I try to execute the `searchTemplate` method I get a parse exception from the server "request body or source parameter is required".

So far I've been reading the documentation but nothing, the guide about the SearchTemplate is very poor.

This is how I'm currently trying to follow the basic steps from the official documentation:

```
SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
    request.setRequest(new SearchRequest(indexPI));

    request.setScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE);
    request.setScript( "{" +
                "  \"query\": { \"match\" : { \"{{field}}\" : \"{{value}}\" } }," +
                "  \"size\" : \"{{size}}\"" +
                "}");

    Map<String, Object> scriptParams = new HashMap<>();

    scriptParams.put("from","");
    scriptParams.put("size","");
    scriptParams.put("field", "title");
    scriptParams.put("value", "elasticsearch");
    scriptParams.put("size", 5);
    request.setScriptParams(scriptParams);

    SearchTemplateResponse response = elasticSearchClient.searchTemplate(request, 
    RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The error I get:

> Elasticsearch exception [type=parse_exception, reason=request body or source parameter is required]

At this point, I'm trying to understand how to set the request body for the above request and actually wondering if it is possible to do.

Any clue about what is missing besides the "unsettable" request body from the exception?